# INET_ATON equivalent in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, maxmind

I can't find any documentation on the web whether there is something like INET_ATON in AWS Redshift. So I guess it isn't there yet but I am wondering if there can be a workaround in some way. BTW I am using max_mind data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a wrapper in Python (which is the main language I am using) which translates IP string into a number and then use it.

Answer (score 2):

For a workaround you can use:

```
SELECT ipAddr, 
   SPLIT_PART(ipAddr, '.', 1)* 16777216::bigint +
   SPLIT_PART(ipAddr, '.', 2)* 65536::bigint +
   SPLIT_PART(ipAddr, '.', 3)* 256::bigint +
   SPLIT_PART(ipAddr, '.', 4)::bigint AS addressRange       
FROM <your_table) LIMIT 5
```

addressRange should match to maxmind startIpNum < addressRange < endIpNum.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the country blocks and locations CSVs in homonymous tables and joined with the following query

```
INSERT INTO dim.geoip_country
SELECT
        SPLIT_PART(first_ip, '.', 1) * 16777216::BIGINT
        + SPLIT_PART(first_ip, '.', 2) * 65536::BIGINT
        + SPLIT_PART(first_ip, '.', 3) * 256::BIGINT
        + SPLIT_PART(first_ip, '.', 4)::BIGINT AS ip_inf,
        SPLIT_PART(first_ip, '.', 1) * 16777216::BIGINT
        + SPLIT_PART(first_ip, '.', 2) * 65536::BIGINT
        + SPLIT_PART(first_ip, '.', 3) * 256::BIGINT
        + SPLIT_PART(first_ip, '.', 4)::BIGINT
        + POW(2, 32 - mask_bits)::BIGINT AS ip_sup,
        network,
        isocode2,
        name,
        continent_code,
        continent_name,
        is_anonymous_proxy,
        is_satellite_provider
FROM (
        SELECT
                b.network,
                SPLIT_PART(b.network, '/', 1) AS first_ip,
                SPLIT_PART(b.network, '/', 2)::INTEGER AS mask_bits,
                l.country_iso_code AS isocode2,
                l.country_name AS name,
                l.continent_code AS continent_code,
                l.continent_name AS continent_name,
                b.is_anonymous_proxy::BOOLEAN AS is_anonymous_proxy,
                b.is_satellite_provider::BOOLEAN AS is_satellite_provider
        FROM ext.geoip2_country_blocks_ipv4 b
        JOIN ext.geoip2_country_locations_en l
                ON b.geoname_id = l.geoname_id
)
```